# Unable to playback ac3 encoded audio stream using gstreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer, gst-launch

Here am trying to playback an ac3 stream using gst-launch-1.0 application. But am getting the following error,

```
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0    /GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind: Could not determine type of stream.
```

The command used here is,

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///usr/bin/*****.ac3
```

Could you please have someone suggest if am missing any plugin here?

Comment: which gstreamer version are you using ? do you have avdec_ac3 plugin installed its part of libav

Comment: yes. This plugin installed. `gst-inspect-1.0 | grep "ac3"
libav:  avdec_eac3: libav ATSC A/52B (AC-3, E-AC-3) decoder
libav:  avdec_atrac3: libav Atrac 3 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding 3) decoder
libav:  avdec_ac3: libav ATSC A/52A (AC-3) decoder
libav:  avenc_eac3: libav ATSC A/52 E-AC-3 encoder
libav:  avenc_ac3_fixed: libav ATSC A/52A (AC-3) encoder
libav:  avenc_ac3: libav ATSC A/52A (AC-3) encoder
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ac3: ac3, eac3
audioparsers:  ac3parse: AC3 audio stream parser
rtp:  rtpac3depay: RTP AC3 depayloader
rtp:  rtpac3pay: RTP AC3 audio payloader
`

Comment: In that case can you try avdec_ac3 and not playbin

Comment: Have tried but still not able to playback the stream. Noticed the following error `0:00:00.152618652  1522      0x17fa630 INFO          GST_SCHEDULING gstpad.c:4275:gst_pad_get_range_unchecked:<filesrc0:src> getrange failed, flow: eos
0:00:00.152653053  1522      0x17fa630 INFO          GST_SCHEDULING gstpad.c:4478:gst_pad_pull_range:<ac3parse0:sink> pullrange failed, flow: eos
`. Also mediainfo shows the tried stream has 6 channels. `Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
`

Comment: what is the complete pipeline you have tried ? Also can you attach the file somewhere it could be downloaded ?